# How to get the elements of a UNION type?

Tags: petri-net, cpn-tools

I have the following declarations:

```
colset AUTHENTICATION = product INT * STRING;
colset REQUEST_PUB = product AUTHENTICATION * STRING * REAL;
colset REQUEST_SUB = product AUTHENTICATION * STRING * INT;
colset REQUEST_PUBSUB = union pub_req:REQUEST_PUB + sub_req:REQUEST_SUB;

var pubsub_req : REQUEST_PUBSUB
```

I have a place of type `REQUEST_PUBSUB` which can receive tokens of both `REQUEST_PUB` and `REQUEST_SUB` types. This place sends the variable `pubsub_req` to a transition. I want to operate with the `pubsub_req` values. For instance, testing if the string parameter of the request is some value. I am trying to do `#3 pubsub_req = "some value"`, but I am getting the following error:

> Error: operator and operand don't agree [type mismatch]
>     operator domain: {3:'Y;'Z}
>     operand: REQUEST_PUBSUB
>     in expression: (fn {3=3,...} => 3) pubsub_req
>     Elaborate failure

How to operate with the elements of a UNION type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of doing as I was trying, I changed the `REQUEST_PUB` type to:

```
colset REQUEST_PUB = product AUTHENTICATION * STRING * INT;
```

Then, I passed a list, such as `((int_var, string_var), string_var, int_var)`, instead of a `REQUEST_PUBSUB` variable. This way I could perform operations in some of the list variables.